# convert Single digit day in R

Tags: r, date, format

I have dates in the format Apr42016, Aug12017, Apr112018. I am trying to convert in Y/m/d using R. I have tried the codes below but when I have a single digit for the day it returned NA. Anyone could help me, please?

```
strptime(data$date, "%b%e%Y")
as.Date (data$date, format="%b%d%Y")
as.POSIXct(data$date, format="%b%e%Y")
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the strings with `sub` (and add a `0` if necessary) before using `as.Date`:

```
myvec <- c("Apr42016", "Aug12017", "Apr112018")  # the data

myvec2 <- sub("(?<=[^0])(?=[0-9]{5})", "0", myvec, perl = TRUE)
# [1] "Apr042016" "Aug012017" "Apr112018"

as.Date(myvec2, format = "%b%d%Y")
# [1] "2016-04-04" "2017-08-01" "2018-04-11"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can break up the numbers before `as.Date`, it will make things much easier. (Borrowing Sven's look-behind.)

```
sub("(?<=\\D)(\\d+)(\\d{4})$", "-\\1-\\2",
  c("Apr42016", "Aug12017", "Apr112018"), perl=TRUE)
# [1] "Apr-4-2016"  "Aug-1-2017"  "Apr-11-2018"
```

From here, the format should be rather straight-forward:

```
as.Date(sub("(?<=\\D)(\\d+)(\\d{4})$", "-\\1-\\2", c("Apr42016", "Aug12017", "Apr112018"), perl = TRUE),
        format="%b-%d-%Y")
# [1] "2016-04-04" "2017-08-01" "2018-04-11"
```